# Filtering and adding a NaN value row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, nan

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
Country     Year    Value
USA         1991     22
USA         1992     3
USA         1993     10
China       1991     1
China       1993     15
Argentina   1991     6
Argentina   1992     4
```

I need a function that could find the missing year for each country and add a row wit a NaN value to the data frame.

```
Country     Year    Value
USA         1991     22
USA         1992     3
USA         1993     10
China       1991     1
China       1992     NaN
China       1993     15
Argentina   1991     6
Argentina   1992     4
Argentina   1993     NaN
```

I need also to create a dataframe with values based only on the years when I have the values for all countries.

```
Country     Year    Value
USA         1991     22
China       1991     1
Argentina   1991     6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Country','Year'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df)
     Country  Year  Value
0  Argentina  1991    6.0
1  Argentina  1992    4.0
2  Argentina  1993    NaN
3      China  1991    1.0
4      China  1992    NaN
5      China  1993   15.0
6        USA  1991   22.0
7        USA  1992    3.0
8        USA  1993   10.0
```

And for groups with no missing values:

```
vals = df1.loc[df1['Value'].isna(), 'Country'].unique()
df2 = df1[~df1['Country'].isin(vals)]
print (df2)
  Country  Year  Value
6     USA  1991   22.0
7     USA  1992    3.0
8     USA  1993   10.0
```

Alternative is use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df.set_index(['Country','Year']).unstack()
df1 = s.stack(dropna=False).reset_index()
print (df1)
     Country  Year  Value
0  Argentina  1991    6.0
1  Argentina  1992    4.0
2  Argentina  1993    NaN
3      China  1991    1.0
4      China  1992    NaN
5      China  1993   15.0
6        USA  1991   22.0
7        USA  1992    3.0
8        USA  1993   10.0
```

For all values per columns use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df2 = s.dropna(axis=1).stack().reset_index()
print (df2)
     Country  Year  Value
0  Argentina  1991    6.0
1      China  1991    1.0
2        USA  1991   22.0
```

EDIT:

If get:

> ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

it means there are not unique combinations of `Country` and `Year` column:

```
print (df)
     Country  Year  Value
0        USA  1991     22 <-duplicate USA, 1991
1        USA  1991      3 <-duplicate USA, 1991
2        USA  1993     10
3      China  1991      1
4      China  1993     15
5  Argentina  1991      6
6  Argentina  1992      4
```

solution is change `set_index` by `groupby` with some aggregate function like `mean`, `sum` for unique combinations:

```
df = df.groupby(['Country','Year']).mean()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df)
     Country  Year  Value
0  Argentina  1991    6.0
1  Argentina  1992    4.0
2  Argentina  1993    NaN
3      China  1991    1.0
4      China  1992    NaN
5      China  1993   15.0
6        USA  1991   12.5
7        USA  1992    NaN
8        USA  1993   10.0
```